# ¿Que permisos usar en un servidor web para wordpress?

Tags: linux

Tengo un subdominio para distintos proyectos en la ruta /var/www/subdominio/public_html

```
sub.dominio.com/proyectoA
sub.dominio.com/proyectoB
sub.dominio.com/proyectoC
```

Tengo dos usuarios en el servidor (root y usuarioA), para poder subir y editar los archivos del template utilizo el usuarioA por medio de SFTP. Suponiendo que tengo que crear un nuevo proyectoD tengo que conectarme por ssh

```
$ cd /var/www/subdominio/public_html
$ mkdir proyectoD
$ cp -r wordpress/* proyectoD/
```

Para que el wordpress permita instalar plugins tengo que ejecutar

```
# chown -R www-data:www-data proyectoD
```

Pero para poder editar los archivos del tema tengo que ejecutar

```
# chown -R usuarioA:www-data proyectoD/wp-content/themes
```

¿Hay una manera de que no tenga que cambiar el dueño del directorio cada vez que cree un nuevo proyecto? Que sólo tenga que crear la carpeta y copiar el contenido del wordpress.tar.gz en el directorio nuevo.

Comment: ¿Mantienes tú ese servidor? Las nuevas formas de implementación de FPM te solucionan todo este tipo de problemas, puedo ayudarte pero si no tienes capacidad para hacer modificaciones grandes e instalación de paquetes en el servidor, de poca ayuda te puedo ser. Coméntame y si eso te pongo como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Copialo mediante el usuario '*root*':

```
$sudo cp -a  wordpress/* proyectoD/
```

El parametro -a funciona como:

-a = -dR y --preserve=all

Es decir Recursivo, Preservando ficheros de tipo link y además conserva los permisos y propietario de los ficheros.

Te puedes ahorrar incluso la creación del directorio (mkdir) y ajuste de permisos del directorio que has creado...

```
$ sudo cp -a wordpress NuevoProyecto
```